Why an attempt to call Iterable<Int>.sum() on a list of Strings fails with complain on inability to cast to java.lang.Number?
Reading 2nd edition of Kotlin in Action.
There is an example with an unsafe cast to a generic List<T> type with an Int assumption for type argument:
fun printSum(c: Collection<*>) {
    val intList = c as? List<Int> // If 'c' is a `List`, it's not guaranteed to be a List of Int's because of type erasure
        ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("List is expected")
    println(intList.sum())
}

The code compiles with a WARNing on unsafe cast and passing a list of strings:
printSum(listOf("a", "b", "c"))

will explode with java.lang.ClassCastException:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.lang.String and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

The ClassCastException is expected, but why the error message complains on a java.lang.Number and not on an Int/java.lang.Integer?
There are no direct references to java.lang.Number class in the code and the sum() function called is an extension on Iterable<Int> (not Iterable<Number>).

As Slaw's answer suggests, this is because the return value of Iterator.next is casted to java.lang.Number.
There is a ticket in YouTrack that addresses this problem - KT-48645. Apparently, this has been an issue ever since Kotlin 1.0. When the return type is a type parameter, the compiler always casts it to java.lang.Number as long as the caller expects a numeric type, no matter what the type argument is specified/inferred to be.
From the ticket:

This appears to be an unintentional side effect of how implicit coercions are implemented in the JVM backend.

There are some quite wild behaviours that result from this. To use an example from the ticket:
val value: Any = 1.2

fun <T> castValue(): T = value as T

fun main() {
    val a = castValue<Long>()
    println(a) // prints "1"!
}


The byte-code of sum has a checkcast instruction against java.lang.Number (see below). But unfortunately, I can't give you an official reason why the Kotlin compiler generates that instruction instead of one that checks against java.lang.Integer.

The implementation of sum looks like (source from version 1.9.24):
/**
 * Returns the sum of all elements in the collection.
 */
@kotlin.jvm.JvmName("sumOfInt")
public fun Iterable<Int>.sum(): Int {
    var sum: Int = 0
    for (element in this) {
        sum += element
    }
    return sum
}

And that results in the following Java byte-code (from kotlin-stdlib-1.9.24.jar and using javap):
public static final int sumOfInt(java.lang.Iterable<java.lang.Integer>);
  descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Iterable;)I
  flags: (0x0019) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=4, args_size=1
        0: aload_0
        1: ldc           #10                 // String <this>
        3: invokestatic  #16                 // Method kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        6: iconst_0
        7: istore_1
        8: aload_0
        9: invokeinterface #95,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/lang/Iterable.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      14: astore_2
      15: aload_2
      16: invokeinterface #101,  1          // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.hasNext:()Z
      21: ifeq          44
      24: aload_2
      25: invokeinterface #105,  1          // InterfaceMethod java/util/Iterator.next:()Ljava/lang/Object;
      30: checkcast     #488                // class java/lang/Number
      33: invokevirtual #489                // Method java/lang/Number.intValue:()I
      36: istore_3
      37: iload_1
      38: iload_3
      39: iadd
      40: istore_1
      41: goto          15
      44: iload_1
      45: ireturn
    StackMapTable: number_of_entries = 2
      frame_type = 253 /* append */
        offset_delta = 15
        locals = [ int, class java/util/Iterator ]
      frame_type = 28 /* same */
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3640: 6
      line 3641: 8
      line 3642: 37
      line 3644: 44
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
          37       4     3 element   I
          8      38     1   sum   I
          0      46     0 $this$sum   Ljava/lang/Iterable;
  Signature: #1548                        // (Ljava/lang/Iterable<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;)I
  RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations:
    0: #819(#820=s#1270)
      kotlin.jvm.JvmName(
        name="sumOfInt"
      )
  RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations:
    parameter 0:
      0: #37()
        org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

The important part in this case is:
30: checkcast     #488                // class java/lang/Number

